# Where to load bulk data in the MEAN+Mongoose stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express, mongoose

In which of the MEAN stack level is it best to load bulk data?  I have about 200 - 800 entries of 2 - 3 different types (i.e. they would require 2 - 3 different Mongoose schemas).

Here are the options to load these data (feel free to point out any misunderstandings, I'm new):

1. Client side: Angular level

   - Automate lots of user inputs
2. Server side: Nodejs + Express + Mongoose

   - Define the schema in Mongoose, create the objects, save each one
3. Database side: Mongodb

   - Make a json file with the data, and import it directly into Mongo:
     `mongoimport -d db_name -c collection_name --jsonArray --file jsonfilename.json`

The third way is the purest and perhaps fastest, but I don't know if it's good to do it at a such low level.

Which one is the best?  If there is not an optimal choice, what would be the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you're bulk loading and if you require validations to be done.

1. Client side: Angular level

   - If you require the user to do the bulk loading and require some human readable error messages that's your choice
2. Server side: Nodejs + Express + Mongoose

   - You can bulk import from a file
   - Expose a REST endpoint to trigger bulk import of your data
   - You can use Mongoose for validation (see [validation in mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html))
   - Mongoose supports creating multiple documents with one call (see [Model.create](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create))
3. Database side: Mongodb

   - Fast, No code needed
   - No flexible validation

I'd choose the option that fits your understanding of the bulk data import best: If it requires a UI your option is 1 combined with 2, if you see this as part of your "business" logic and you're importing data from a external file or want other systems to trigger that import your option is 2, if you see it as a one time action to import data or you don't require any validation or logic related to the import the best choice is option 3.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer! I'm leaning towards #2. Would you mind adding more detail on the first two bullets of #2: "You can bulk import from a file. Expose a REST endpoint to trigger bulk import of your data"? Thank you so much!

Comment: Importing from a file is quite clear, you can read for example a json file and use a mongodb driver to insert entries into mongodb. You can also create a route handler in express that accepts post request containing the data to import

Comment: Just to clarify, for "You can bulk import from a file" it means importing via mongodb even though that bullet is under "Nodejs + Express + Mongoose"?

Answer (score 0):

Loading it via the client side will require you to write more code to handle importing and to send to the backend, then handle it in Node.js.

The fastest method out of all of them would be to directly import it the data using `mongoimport`.